# Cordova: Geolocation - Error Callback don't work

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I used the example from the documentation. I get the alert with my coordinates, but if i block GPS or turn it off, nothing happens. If I replace 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
with
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onError);
the alert is shown.

Anyone an idea?

here's the code, known from documentation

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    //AKTUELLE POSITION ERMITTELN
    var onSuccess = function(position)
    {
        alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
              'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
              'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
              'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
              'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
              'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
              'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
    }

    //Error Callback für eigene Position
    function onError(error)
    {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

Comment: How do you use your callbacks?

Comment: i'll post the code as an edit in my first post in a moment

Comment: Does none of the callbacks fire when you disable locations?

Comment: don't seem so. i don't get an alert, no error in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    //AKTUELLE POSITION ERMITTELN
    function onSuccess(success)
    {
        alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
              'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
              'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
              'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
              'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
              'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
              'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
    }

    //Error Callback für eigene Position
    function onError(error)
    {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```